# R.java file never generated

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

I'm brand new to Eclipse for Android Developers (Eclipse Neon in Ubuntu), and upon creating my first project, I was flooded with errors. It appears that the source of the errors was that the R.java file was never generated.

I've attempted to clean the project and restore from local history (nothing was ever deleted so this accomplished nothing). I've been unable to find a solution to my R.java file never existing in the first place, and help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: R.java will be generated automatically after a build. Did you trying building the project again after cleaning? And please check if the import of your classes contains `com.yourpackage.R`

Comment: I now believe that the problem may be because of an xml file with an error. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Main Reason behind R.java File not generated is :-

First of all i think that is the Problem of your XML file.if you Leave any Mistakes/Errors on your XML file.

Then Eclipse/Android Studio will never generate an R.java.

That is the Solution of your Problem.

Hope this help to generate your File..(:

Answer (score 0):

Try to **create project Again** (Delete it and create New)
Either your **Eclipse is not installed properly**.
Any file is missing in Eclipse (While installing it, Antivirus removes some important files, So install **Re-install Eclipse keeping your antivirus paused**.